# Github's multiple projects access on Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have an Organization level Github and I want to access all its projects with single ssh key or single credential in my Jenkins. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Just follow [this instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) to:

- [generate ssh key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)
- [add new key to github account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)

Then it should just work as long as your jenkins uses this ssh key to connect to github, download repos etc.